# Fixed header for tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I have a table view and I would like to attach a header to the top of this tableview so that the table scrollview beneath it. Please how can I do this? Possibly in code?

Answer (score 0):

Create your header as a class that derives from `UIView` and then position it above the `UITableView`.

Comment: I proceeded to do something this     
    EventCell       *headerViewCell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"EventCellView" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0
    tableView.tableHeaderView = headerViewCell; What I find that it scrolls just like any other cell. Please advise.